# $Res(f,z_0)=0\implies f $ is analytic at $z _0 $?, $z _0 $ is a simple pole.

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you explain (or refer to results from which this follows ) that if $\operatorname{Res}(f,z_0)=0$ then $ f $ is analytic at $z _0 $?

Edit:
Also $f $ has at most simple poles as singularities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know that $f$ has at most simple poles as singularities, it follows.

Comment: Yes, this is the additinal assumption. I will add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$$

**Edit:** if you have at most simple pole singularities the Laurent series around any point $z_0$ is 
$$f(z)=\frac{c_{-1}}{z-z_0}+c_{0}+c_{1}(z-z_0)+\dots$$
$\mbox{Res}(f,z_0)=c_{-1}$, so  $\mbox{Res}(f,z_0)=0$ implies
$$f(z)=c_{0}+c_{1}(z-z_0)+\dots$$
i.e. $f$ is analytic in $z_0$.

Comment: Ok, I will look for additional assumptions!